# Can i customize the magento back end for admin users?

Tags: php, magento, customization

I am making an ecommerce website using magento.. I want to know if i can customize the back end as per my requirement.

Example : In the manage products page i want to create a custom page and give the admin users the option to easily add the products (Most of the values will be taken by default) and some will be chosen by user (I want to change the default UI and functionality for the admin users)

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible ... Hope it helped you.

Comment: Can you suggest any link or reference for this sort of example ??

Comment: hu no .. your question is as vague as "can i customize frontoffice?". it's obviously YES.. Next, what have you tried? do you need help coding it ? well OK but show some code. If not, take a look a magento modules sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bixi .. I Just wanted to know if it can be done somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can develope a simple module or a simple php one-file-script and add products easily using Magento API. You can set default values to some attributes inline.

I found a blog post, I don't recommend to use that code because it looks messy, but it will give you a hint;

http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/automated-quick-simple-product-creation-in-magento/

Also, there's a non-free module in magento connect named "Quick Product Add". It looks like what you need but I didn't test it and this is not a recommendation. You can find it here;

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/quick-product-creation.html